# How do I automate the export different layers combinations ( turning on and off ) in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, export, automation

I have a comp that has various layers that I would like to toggle on and off in combination. Lets say I would like to turn on and off layer to create 60 distinct combinations. I do this by hand, add to the render queue one at a time and then export, but this is a real pain.  Is there any way in after effects ( perhaps even through scripting ) to create something like "layers comps" and "layer comps to files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templater can do this.
https://aescripts.com/templater/
You feed it a load of google (or excel or CSV) tables, with specified values, and it can churn through a load of files to export different comps with different arrangements.